# Razor: Why is my variable not in scope

Tags: c#, razor

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using System.Collections;

@{ List<string> qa = new List<string>(); } //this is not defined in the recursive helper below

@helper traverseFirst(dynamic node){
   var items = node.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide != true");
   foreach (var item in items) {
     foreach(var subItem in item.Descendants()) {
        if(subItem.Id == Model.Id)
        {
           qa.Add();
           break;
        }
     }
     @traverseFirst(item)
   }
}

@traverseFirst(@Model.AncestorOrSelf("Book"))
```

The variable qa canot be accessed in the recursive helper. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Define the variable in a `@functions` section.

The normal `@{` places your code in some method body. Use `@functions` to define class members.

```
@functions{ List<string> qa = new List<string>(); }
```

More reading on this matter: [SLaks Dissecting razor](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-6-function-blocks.html) series.

Answer (score -1):

In Razor 3.2.3 it seems the variable declared in `@functions` need to be declared `static`.  Seems unfortunate.  Please correct me if there is an alternative way.

```
@functions
{
    static List<string> qa = new List<string>();
}

@helper traverseFirst(dynamic node)
{
   var items = node.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide != true");
   foreach (var item in items) {
     foreach(var subItem in item.Descendants()) {
        if(subItem.Id == Model.Id)
        {
           qa.Add();
           break;
        }
     }
     @traverseFirst(item)
   }
}
```

Comment: No no no no no. This is a terrible idea! If two people hit your page at the same time the value will get overwritten - plus it will just be sitting around and not get garbaged collected (less of a problem).