# How to declare a variable in view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `view` in `asp.net-mvc4` application that access data from `controller` and `model`.

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewExampleDatabase4.Models.Messung>

@section Scripts{
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datefield").datepicker();
    });


</script>
}

<table style="background-color: #009963; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px;   
text-align:    center;" width="740" height="20" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border="1">
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #009963; color: #FFFFFF" colspan="3">
    <b> Messungen für Fahrzeug : @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Fahrzeugname)       </b>
</td>
</tr>
</table> 



@using (Html.BeginForm("ForFahrzeug", "Messungen", FormMethod.Get))
{     
     <!--Messungsart: @Html.DropDownList("Total")-->   
      <P>Messungen der letzten Tage: @Html.TextBox("days", "30", new { style =   
"width:5%"     }) Oder Messungen begin von:
      @Html.TextBox("initDate" ,"", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" })     
und    Ende: 
      @Html.TextBox("finalDate" ,"", new { style = "width:15%", @class = "datefield" })   


     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> </p> 
} 




<table>

 var total = 0;

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   total  =  total + item.t_Gesamtzeit_s_msg; 




if(Model.Last()==item)
{
  <table style="background-color: #009963; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 12px;    
text-align: center; " width="740" height="30" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">

  <tr>
     <td style="background-color: #009963; color: #FFFFFF" colspan="3"> Summary </td>
  </tr>

  <tr style = "border:1px solid #FFFFFF">
     <td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid #FFFFFF"> 
 <b>Gesamtzeit</b></td>
     <td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid 
 #FFFFFF">@Html.Raw(total)</td>
     <td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid 
 #FFFFFF">Messende</td>
     <td style="background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000; border:1px solid #FFFFFF"></td>
  </tr>


  </table>   
 }

 }


</table>


 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) 
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Messbeginn)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Messende)
    </th>

</tr>


 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {

<tr>
    <td width="8%">            
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "MessungsDetail", "Messungen", new { id = item.ID },   
null) 
    </td>
    <!--<td width="35%">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Beschreibung)
    </td>-->
    <td width="10%">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Messbeginn)
    </td>
    <td width="8%">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Messende)
    </td>        
    <!--<td width="10%">
        @Html.ActionLink("Download", "ForDownload", "Messungen", new { id = item.ID },  
 null)            
    </td>-->
</tr>
 }


 </table>
```

As I have declard a variable `total`. But when I using it for increment. it gives erorr. I need a variable to use.

Comment: Don't put logic like that in the View, it doesn't belong there. Create a property for the total on your model and calculate the Total before you pass it to the view. Also add script tags to the bottom of your page so it loads faster

Comment: possible duplicate: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069213/razor-why-is-my-variable-not-in-scope ?

Comment: @{ c# code block } all variables should be declare in this block aur simple @total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a code-block:

```
@{ var total = 0; }
```

Because you have "HTML markup" before this it is not "auto-detected" like the `total = total + item.t_Gesamtzeit_s_msg;` is after the `@foreach`.

**BUT** as already said in the comments: This should be handled by the model and not the view.

**AND** I would also recommend to use english names only, as it could cause maintainability problems if later on a "non-german-speaker" should maintain the code.